# java concurrency: many writers, one reader

Tags: java, concurrency

I need to gather some statistics in my software and i am trying to make it fast and correct, which is not easy (for me!)

first my code so far with two classes, a StatsService and a StatsHarvester

```
public class StatsService
{
private Map<String, Long>   stats   = new HashMap<String, Long>(1000);

public void notify ( String key )
{
    Long value = 1l;
    synchronized (stats)
    {
        if (stats.containsKey(key))
        {
            value = stats.get(key) + 1;
        }
        stats.put(key, value);
    }
}

public Map<String, Long> getStats ( )
{
    Map<String, Long> copy;
    synchronized (stats)
    {
        copy = new HashMap<String, Long>(stats);
        stats.clear();
    }
    return copy;
}
}
```

this is my second class, a harvester which collects the stats from time to time and writes them to a database.

```
public class StatsHarvester implements Runnable
{
private StatsService    statsService;
private Thread          t;

public void init ( )
{
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

public synchronized void run ( )
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            wait(5 * 60 * 1000); // 5 minutes
            collectAndSave();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void collectAndSave ( )
{
    Map<String, Long> stats = statsService.getStats();
    // do something like:
    // saveRecords(stats);
}
}
```

At runtime it will have about 30 concurrent running threads each calling `notify(key)` about 100 times. Only one StatsHarvester is calling `statsService.getStats()`

So i have many writers and only one reader. it would be nice to have accurate stats but i don't care if some records are lost on high concurrency.

The reader should run every 5 Minutes or whatever is reasonable.

Writing should be as fast as possible. Reading should be fast but if it locks for about 300ms every 5 minutes, its fine.

I've read many docs (Java concurrency in practice, effective java and so on), but i have the strong feeling that i need your advice to get it right.

I hope i stated my problem clear and short enough to get valuable help.

---

### EDIT

Thanks to all for your detailed and helpful answers. As i expected there is more than one way to do it.

I tested most of your proposals (those i understood) and uploaded a test project to google code for further reference (maven project)

http://code.google.com/p/javastats/

I have tested different implementations of my StatsService

- HashMapStatsService (HMSS)
- ConcurrentHashMapStatsService (CHMSS)
- LinkedQueueStatsService (LQSS)
- GoogleStatsService (GSS)
- ExecutorConcurrentHashMapStatsService (ECHMSS)
- ExecutorHashMapStatsService (EHMSS)

and i tested them with `x` number of Threads each calling notify `y` times, results are in ms

```
         10,100   10,1000  10,5000  50,100   50,1000  50,5000  100,100  100,1000 100,5000 
GSS       1        5        17       7        21       117      7        37       254       Summe: 466
ECHMSS    1        6        21       5        32       132      8        54       249       Summe: 508
HMSS      1        8        45       8        52       233      11       103      449       Summe: 910
EHMSS     1        5        24       7        31       113      8        67       235       Summe: 491
CHMSS     1        2        9        3        11       40       7        26       72        Summe: 171
LQSS      0        3        11       3        16       56       6        27       144       Summe: 266
```

At this moment i think i will use ConcurrentHashMap, as it offers good performance while it is quite easy to understand.

Thanks for all your input!
Janning

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to change the state of an object while holding a lock on it. Also there should be no need to synchronize the `run()` method in `StatsHarvester`.

Comment: `synchronized` keyword in below snipped (in CHMSS) seems to be unnecessary. Unless you are harvesting stats using multiple threads concurrently (obviously, if so that seems odd). Even if you put `synchronized` there, it won't stop threads from calling notify() anyway. If I were you, I'd not bother because stats don't have to be "100%" accurate. If you use CHM, there is no way to lock the entire map.

 synchronized (stats)
                {
                        copy = new HashMap<String, Number>(stats);
                        stats.clear();
                }
                return copy;

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As jack was eluding to you can use the java.util.concurrent library which includes a ConcurrentHashMap and AtomicLong.  You can put the AtomicLong in if absent else, you can increment the value.  Since AtomicLong is thread safe you will be able to increment the variable without worry about a concurrency issue.

```
public void notify(String key) {
    AtomicLong value = stats.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        value = stats.putIfAbsent(key, new AtomicLong(1));
    }
    if (value != null) {
        value.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

This should be both fast and thread safe

Edit: Refactored sligthly so there is only at most two lookups.

Comment: @BalusC: The docs say it returns "the previous value associated with the specified key, or null if there was no mapping for the key". Your one liner will throw a NullPointerException the first time a particular key is notified.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, you're right (removed wrong comment). Still, this approach is a bit inefficient. I'd rewrite it like follows: `AtomicLong value = stats.get(key); if (value == null) { value = new AtomicLong(0); stats.put(key, value); } value.incrementAndGet();`. Now the map is scanned at least only once instead of at least two times.

Comment: @BalausC thats not atomic though. What if stats.put replaces a put by another thread in between your if and stats.put?

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link. Using `putIfAbsent()` is more a matter of threadsafety, not efficiency.

Comment: @Mattias you are doing a global lock on all writes then, you will punish the ConcurrentHashMap's throughput. The ConcurrentHashMap was written specifically to allow for concurrent writes on non colliding entries. In best case scenario my solution will only block a single entry once per key.

Comment: According to javadoc, you don't need the first call to stats.get or the first null check. putIfAbsent will either return the previous mapped value (in which case you should increment), or null if there was no previous value, in which case the provided AtomicLong(1) was inserted.

Comment: Yes however, continously calling putIfAbsent is not the correct way of using ConcurrentHashMap.  For every single putIfAbsent you will lock a single entry that is associated to the hashCode.  You are doing a needless lock where as if you succeed with the initial get you will never block.

Comment: This solution do not address the problems on the second method, getStats. Copy and clear operations are not atomic.

Comment: I posted an answer to address those problems, I hope it help you.

Comment: @johnvint The code you provided has a problem - if `value` is `null` the `putIfAbsent` will also return `null` so `value` will stay `null`. So the code as it is written now is correct but misleading. You either shouldn't assign the return value from `putIfAbsent` into `value` or you should initialize `value` to some real value.

Comment: @SatA I am confused about your point.  If the `value` is initially null (which means it doesn't exist yet in the map), we will try to place a `new AtomicLong(1)` into the map.  The ConcurrentMap will return either null if the put was successful or the value that already existed in the map if the put wasn't successful.  So when we get a non-null `value` from `putIfAbsent` that means another thread won in executing the put first, so we should `incrementAndGet`.

Comment: `So the code as it is written now is correct but misleading.` I disagree that it is misleading but I guess that's personal preference.

Comment: @johnvint Sorry for not being clear. What I meant was that you assign the return value of `putIfAbsent` into `value` but in that case it will always be `null` so I don't see why you would do that since `value` was `null` before the call and stays `null` after. I guess that if someone would take this code, use it and change it a bit (as I did) he would stumble upon this very quickly and make the necessary changes. I just wanted to point out that the assignment is meaningless\pointless. Not such a big issue though.

Comment: Thinking about it, it is only relevant when speaking about a multi-threaded situation where multiple threads call this function and there is a change that `putIfAbsent` may return a value as you wrote. So, yep +1 for that then :)

Comment: @SatA Oh yes! I see where the confusion was.  In a single threaded execution this code looks strange.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you use [`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)? It handles everything internally avoiding useless locks on the map and saving you a lot of work: you won't have to care about synchronizations on get and put..

From the documentation:

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable expected concurrency for updates. This class obeys the same functional specification as Hashtable, and includes versions of methods corresponding to each method of Hashtable. **However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking**, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access.

You can specify its *concurrency level*:

> **The allowed concurrency among update operations is guided by the optional concurrencyLevel constructor argument (default 16), which is used as a hint for internal sizing**. The table is internally partitioned to try to permit the indicated number of concurrent updates without contention. Because placement in hash tables is essentially random, the actual concurrency will vary. **Ideally, you should choose a value to accommodate as many threads as will ever concurrently modify the table**. Using a significantly higher value than you need can waste space and time, and a significantly lower value can lead to thread contention. But overestimates and underestimates within an order of magnitude do not usually have much noticeable impact. A value of one is appropriate when it is known that only one thread will modify and all others will only read. Also, resizing this or any other kind of hash table is a relatively slow operation, so, when possible, it is a good idea to provide estimates of expected table sizes in constructors.

As suggested in comments read carefully the documentation of [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), especially when it states about atomic or not atomic operations.

To have the guarantee of atomicity you should consider which operations are atomic, from `ConcurrentMap` interface you will know that:

```
V putIfAbsent(K key, V value)
V replace(K key, V value)
boolean replace(K key,V oldValue, V newValue)
boolean remove(Object key, Object value)
```

can be used safely.

Comment: It's worth noting that this approach could very easily lead to lost updates.

Comment: According to __Map__ contract it shouldn't allow lost updates, assuming also that __putIfAbsent__ is executed atomically.

Comment: To ensure that, you'll need to loop until `replace(key, currentValue, currentValue+1)` returns true.

Comment: you might want to consider mentioning `putIfAbsent` in your main post. While the individual operations of ConcurrentHashMap are thread-safe, compound operations naturally are not.

Comment: In addition AtomicLong / AtomicInteger should be considered as the map values, this would eliminate the issue of lost increments (except potentially on the initial populations, unless the keys are all pre-populated or a call to putIfAbsent is included as pointed out by matt b.).

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest taking a look at Java's util.concurrent library. I think you can implement this solution a lot cleaner. I don't think you need a map here at all. I would recommend implementing this using the [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html). Each 'producer' can freely write to this queue without worrying about others. It can put an object on the queue with the data for its statistics.

The harvester can consume the queue continually pulling data off and processsing it. It can then store it however it needs.

Answer (score 4):

Chris Dail's answer looks like a good approach.

Another alternative would be to use a concurrent `Multiset`.  There is one in the [Google Collections library](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ConcurrentHashMultiset.html).  You could use this as follows:

```
private Multiset<String> stats = ConcurrentHashMultiset.create();

public void notify ( String key )
{
    stats.add(key, 1);
}
```

Looking at the [source](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/ConcurrentHashMultiset.java), this is implemented using a `ConcurrentHashMap` and using `putIfAbsent` and the three-argument version of `replace` to detect concurrent modifications and retry.

Answer (score 3):

A different approach to the problem is to exploit the (trivial) thread safety via thread confinement. Basically create a single background thread that takes care of both reading and writing. It has a pretty good characteristics in terms of scalability and simplicity.

The idea is that instead of all the threads trying to update the data directly, they produce an "update" task for the background thread to process. The same thread can also do the read task, assuming some lags in processing updates is tolerable.

This design is pretty nice because the threads will no longer have to compete for a lock to update data, and since the map is confined to a single thread you can simply use a plain HashMap to do get/put, etc. In terms of implementation, it would mean creating a single threaded executor, and submitting write tasks which may also perform the optional "collectAndSave" operation.

A sketch of code may look like the following:

```
public class StatsService {
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private final Map<String,Long> stats = new HashMap<String,Long>();

    public void notify(final String key) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Long value = stats.get(key);
                if (value == null) {
                    value = 1L;
                } else {
                    value++;
                }
                stats.put(key, value);
                // do the optional collectAndSave periodically
                if (timeToDoCollectAndSave()) {
                    collectAndSave();
                }
            }
        };
        executor.execute(r);
    }
}
```

There is a BlockingQueue associated with an executor, and each thread that produces a task for the StatsService uses the BlockingQueue. The key point is this: **the locking duration for this operation should be much shorter** than the locking duration in the original code, so the contention should be much less. Overall it should result in a much better throughput and latency.

Another benefit is that since only one thread reads and writes to the map, plain HashMap and primitive long type can be used (no ConcurrentHashMap or atomic types involved). This also simplifies the code that actually processes it a great deal.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do not understand your post. Sorry, but aren't you shifting the problem to another place. When you say "produce an update task" you have to put that in a map or queue whatever data structure you like. And you have to synchronize this.

Comment: yes much clearer. thanks a lot. i upvoted your answer. I am going to test your approach but i think The BlockingQueue must be synchronized in some way. So you move the synchronization from StatsService to the ExecutorService. But i will check it and edit my post to make my results available.

Comment: -1. This is a very inefficient solution.  Also you are missing a `put` after the increment.

Comment: @finnw Thanks for pointing out the error in the code. I corrected it.

As for the efficacy of the solution, (along with most things in life) it depends. When compared against using a ConcurrentHashMap (thus no synchronization being done), it does not perform better. However, if the original solution involves synchronization, this is a very useful alternative. Essentially, it's an asynchronous solution to the problem. Obviously it minimizes the latency from the viewpoint of the threads that generate these tasks. Second, it eliminates lock contention associated with the locking involved.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)? You could use that to schedule your writers, which could all write to a concurrent collection, such as the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` mentioned by @Chris Dail. You can have a separately schedule job to read from the Queue as necessary, and the Java SDK should handle pretty much all your concurrency concerns, no manual locking needed.

Answer (score 0):

If we ignore the harvesting part and focus on the writing, the main bottleneck of the program is that the stats are locked at a very coarse level of granularity. If two threads want to update different keys, they must wait.

If you know the set of keys in advance, and can preinitialize the map so that by the time an update thread arrives the key is guaranteed to exist, you would be able to do locking on the accumulator variable instead of the whole map, or use a thread-safe accumulator object.

Instead of implementing this yourself, there are map implementations that are designed specifically for concurrency and do this more fine-grained locking for you.

One caveat though are the stats, since you would need to get locks on all the accumulators at roughly the same time. If you use an existing concurrency-friendly map, there might be a construct for getting a snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for implement both methods using [ReentranReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). This implementation protects against race conditions at getStats method, if you need to clear the counters. Also it removes the mutable AtomicLong from the getStats an uses an immutable Long.

```
public class StatsService {

    private final Map<String, AtomicLong> stats = new HashMap<String, AtomicLong>(1000);
    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock r = rwl.readLock();
    private final Lock w = rwl.writeLock();

    public void  notify(final String key) {
        r.lock();
        AtomicLong count = stats.get(key);
        if (count == null) {
            r.unlock();
            w.lock();
            count = stats.get(key);
            if(count == null) { 
                count = new AtomicLong();
                stats.put(key, count);
            }
            r.lock();
            w.unlock();
        }
        count.incrementAndGet();
        r.unlock();
    }

    public Map<String, Long> getStats() {
        w.lock();

        Map<String, Long> copy = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        for(Entry<String,AtomicLong> entry : stats.entrySet() ){
                copy.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().longValue());
        }
        stats.clear();
        w.unlock();

        return copy;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps, any comments are welcome!

Comment: There is a deadlock when use call r.lock() before w.unlock();

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with minimal impact on the performance of the threads being measured. This is the fastest solution possible in Java, without resorting to special hardware registers for performance counting.

Have each thread output its stats independently of the others, that is with no synchronization, to some stats object. Make the field containing the count volatile, so it is memory fenced:

```
class Stats
{
   public volatile long count;
}

class SomeRunnable implements Runnable
{
   public void run()
   {
     doStuff();
     stats.count++;
   }
}
```

Have another thread, that holds a reference to all the Stats objects, periodically go around them all and add up the counts across all threads:

```
public long accumulateStats()
{
   long count = previousCount;

   for (Stats stat : allStats)
   {
       count += stat.count;
   }

   long resultDelta = count - previousCount;
   previousCount = count;

   return resultDelta;
}
```

This gatherer thread also needs a sleep() (or some other throttle) added to it. It can periodically output counts/sec to the console for example, to give you a "live" view of how your application is performing.

This avoids the synchronization overhead about as much as you can.

The other trick to consider is padding the Stats objects to 128 (or 256 bytes on SandyBridge or later), so as to keep the different threads counts on different cache lines, or there will be caching contention on the CPU.

When only one thread reads and one writes, you do not need locks or atomics, a volatile is sufficient. There will still be some thread contention, when the stats reader thread interacts with the CPU cache line of the thread being measured. This cannot be avoided, but it is the way to do it with minimal impact on the running thread; read the stats maybe once a second or less.

Comment: Thought you may appreciate this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html

Comment: Thanks, I have not really checked out Java 8 yet. Would be interesting to compare with my solution, which is very minimal, to check if it has any extra overhead in comparison. One thing that may differ, the counts for the threads, are they held in ThreadLocal? I avoided that by making each thread explicitly create its own Stats object. Less transparent/simple to use, but avoids the use of ThreadLocal (not that ThreadLocal is so slow any more).

Comment: This answer should really get some up-votes, because it is way faster than the other answers. I suppose in many cases extremely light-weight stats gathering may not be so important, as the tasks being measured may be so long and heavy weight. But if you really need your stats gathering to slow down the code as little as possible, this is the way to do it.

Comment: What you gain in throughput you lose in consistency. A classic trade-off.  This flavor of solution would be best if you need an approximate value but not necessarily the exact value at a moment in time.  The StampedLock docs even say something similar.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can stop the world with a lock to get an 'exact' value, but the lock will be obtained in a non-deterministic fashion anyway, so the result is no more exact than mine. The important thing is that counts will not be counted twice or missed, and the memory fencing on the volatile ensures the reads and writes to it are consistent. Basically, if you have one thread reading and one writing, you don't need locks or atomics, a volatile is sufficient.